# The cnosdb process received a signal 11 and was killed

Tags: linux, database, time-series, cnosdb

The cnosdb process received a signal 11 and was killed. And I check the docker container logs as follow:

```
2023-09-25T11:15:54.356654435Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":851061022720,"time":1695640554,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-09-25T11:16:24.349315980Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /data_version :225518
2023-09-25T11:16:24.349376748Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: METADATA WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":851050586112,"time":1695640584,"status":"Healthy"}
Signal 11, Stack trace for thread "tokio-runtime-worker"
   0: cnosdb::signal::install_crash_handler::signal_handler
   1: <unknown>
   2: tskv::reader::iterator::open_field_file_location::{{closure}}
   3: <futures_util::future::join_all::JoinAll<F> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
   4: tskv::reader::iterator::SeriesGroupRowIterator::build_field_cursor::{{closure}}
   5: tskv::reader::iterator::SeriesGroupRowIterator::fetch_next_row::{{closure}}
   6: tskv::reader::iterator::RowIterator::new_series_group_iteration::{{closure}}
   7: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll
   8: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::Context::run_task
   9: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::run
  10: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll
  11: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
  12: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}
  13: <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once
             at rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1987:9
      <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once
             at rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1987:9
      std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start
             at rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/sys/unix/thread.rs:108:17
  14: start_thread
  15: clone
```

I start the single mode as follow:

```
docker run -d -v /data1/DF_OSS_SI/data/:/data/ -p 12002:8902 --name dfosssi cnosdb/cnosdb:community-2.3 cnosdb run -M singleton
```

And use tsdb-parisons tool load data,run queries as follow:

```
# load data;
set -e errexit
times=1
while true
do
  /bin/cat /data/data/line_protocol/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_data.gz| /bin/gunzip | /bin/load_cnosdb --batch-size 1 --workers 1 --urls "http://192.xxx.xxx.21:12002" > insert.log 
  sleep 1
  ((times++))
done


# run queries
set -e errexit
times=1
while true
do
  echo "long-driving-session:${times}"
  run_queries_cnosdb --file /data/data/query/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_long-driving-sessions_10000 --urls "http://192.168.0.21:12002" >> query.log
  sleep 1
  echo "high-load:${times}"
  run_queries_cnosdb --file /data/data/query/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_high-load_10000 --urls "http://192.168.0.21:12002" >> query.log
  sleep 1
  echo "last-loc:${times}"
  run_queries_cnosdb --file /data/data/query/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_last-loc_10000 --urls "http://192.168.0.21:12002" >> query.log
  sleep 1
  echo "low-fuel:${times}"
  run_queries_cnosdb --file /data/data/query/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_low-fuel_10000 --urls "http://192.168.0.21:12002" >> query.log
  sleep 1
  echo "stationary-trucks:${times}"
  run_queries_cnosdb --file /data/data/query/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_stationary-trucks_10000 --urls "http://192.168.0.21:12002" >> query.log
  sleep 1
  echo "avg-daily-driving-duration:${times}"
  run_queries_cnosdb --file /data/data/query/cnosdb_iot_123_100_6.3_2020-2025_5y_avg-daily-driving-duration_10000 --urls "http://192.168.0.21:12002" >> query.log
  sleep 1
  ((times++))
done
```

After running for about two weeks, the cnosdb process was killed by os.

And check the disk, there is no space:

```
/dev/xxx1n1p1             894G  894G   20K  100% /data1
overlay                    894G  894G   20K  100% /data1/docker/overlay2/xxx/merged
```

Is this because the disk space is exhausted, causing the process to be killed?According to the previous practice, insufficient disk space should result in a log saying: no space left.

dmesg -T

```
 traps: crond[13660] general protection ip:7f4c5a33f307 sp:7fffe8d57008 error:0 in libpthread-2.17.so[7f4c5a338000+17000]
[一 9月 25 07:27:35 2023] docker0: port 1(veth9fafe4c) entered disabled state
[一 9月 25 07:27:35 2023] docker0: port 1(veth9fafe4c) entered disabled state
[一 9月 25 07:27:36 2023] device veth9fafe4c left promiscuous mode
[一 9月 25 07:27:36 2023] docker0: port 1(veth9fafe4c) entered disabled state
```

Comment: It appears to be due to memory fragmentation errors. Your application tries to access invalid memory location or writing more than OS buffer size. You need to take coredumps to analyse the stacktrace leading to this error. 

Do you see some errors in `dmesg` output?

Comment: @harshavmb It may be a problem with previous settings. I also checked the core dump directory and no relevant files were generated.The dmesg log during the time period when the problem occurred is as above